# can't generate abi when using map

Tags: abi, abigen

I am trying to use this :

```
struct [[eosio::table]] tokens {
                name token;
                std::map<name,asset> blnc;
                uint64_t primary_key() const { return token.value; }
            };
```

But I get the following error :

> error: error reading '/home/ubuntu/exchange.cpp' 1 error generated.
>   Error while processing /home/ubuntu/exchange.cpp. abigen error

Is there a problem with using maps in tables in `eosio-cpp`?

Comment: Where is template argument for your map? What version of CDT do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have used maps in a table without issue before, my table looks like this:

```
  class [[ eosio::table("ram"), eosio::contract("automatedres") ]] ram_t
  {
  private:
    eosio::time_point created;

  public:
    std::map< eosio::name, int64_t > ram_usage;
    std::map< eosio::name, bool > paid_chex; ///@todo Create modifier and accessor functions
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return created.sec_since_epoch(); }
    auto set_created(eosio::time_point const &x) { created = x; }
    auto get_created() const { return created; }
  };
  typedef eosio::multi_index< eosio::name("ram"), ram_t > ram_table;
```

If this doesn't work for you, then perhaps you are using an older version of the `eosio.cdt` or something. Upgrade to the latest version of the software and check again.